# How to present iOS UIActionSheet in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiactionsheet

How can I present a UIActionSheet in Swift within an iOS app?

Here is my code for displaying a UIActionSheet:

```
@IBAction func downloadSheet(sender: AnyObject) {
    let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Choose Option", preferredStyle: .actionSheet) 

    let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        println("Saved")
    })
    
    let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .default, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        println("Deleted")
    })
    
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        println("Cancelled")
    })
    optionMenu.addAction(deleteAction)
    optionMenu.addAction(saveAction)
    optionMenu.addAction(cancelAction)
    self.presentViewController(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I think your approach is good, because from ios8 UIActionSheet is deprecated. So your style is preferred.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Your Approach is fine, but you can add `UIActionSheet` with other way with ease.

You can add `UIActionSheetDelegate` in UIViewController` like

```
class ViewController: UIViewController ,UIActionSheetDelegate
```

Set you method like,

```
@IBAction func downloadSheet(sender: AnyObject)
{

    let actionSheet = UIActionSheet(title: "Choose Option", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", destructiveButtonTitle: nil, otherButtonTitles: "Save", "Delete")

    actionSheet.showInView(self.view)
}
```

You can get your button index when it clicked like

```
func actionSheet(actionSheet: UIActionSheet, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int)
{
    println("\(buttonIndex)")
    switch (buttonIndex){

    case 0:
        println("Cancel")
    case 1:
        println("Save")
    case 2:
        println("Delete")
    default:
        println("Default")
        //Some code here..

    }
}
```

Update 1: for iOS8+

```
    //Create the AlertController and add Its action like button in Actionsheet
    let actionSheetControllerIOS8: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Please select", message: "Option to select", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

    let cancelActionButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { _ in
        print("Cancel")
    }
    actionSheetControllerIOS8.addAction(cancelActionButton)

    let saveActionButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default)
        { _ in
           print("Save")
    }
    actionSheetControllerIOS8.addAction(saveActionButton)

    let deleteActionButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .default)
        { _ in
            print("Delete")
    }
    actionSheetControllerIOS8.addAction(deleteActionButton)
    self.present(actionSheetControllerIOS8, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: UIActionSheet is deprecated in iOS 8. (Note that UIActionSheetDelegate is also deprecated.) To create and manage action sheets in iOS 8 and later, instead use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet.     see detail : https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/index.html

Answer (score 171):

**Updated for Swift 4/5**

**Works for iOS 11-14**

Some of the other answers are okay but I ended up mixing and matching a few of them to rather come up with this :

```
@IBAction func showAlert(sender: AnyObject) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Please Select an Option", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Approve", style: .default , handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in
        print("User click Approve button")
    }))
    
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Edit", style: .default , handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in
        print("User click Edit button")
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive , handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in
        print("User click Delete button")
    }))
    
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .cancel, handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in
        print("User click Dismiss button")
    }))

    
    //uncomment for iPad Support
    //alert.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {
        print("completion block")
    })
}
```

Enjoy **:)**

Answer (score 41):

`UIActionSheet` is deprecated in iOS 8.

I am using following:

```
// Create the AlertController
let actionSheetController = UIAlertController(title: "Please select", message: "How you would like to utilize the app?", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

// Create and add the Cancel action
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { action -> Void in
    // Just dismiss the action sheet
}
actionSheetController.addAction(cancelAction)

// Create and add first option action
let takePictureAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Consumer", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue_setup_customer", sender: self)
}
actionSheetController.addAction(takePictureAction)

// Create and add a second option action
let choosePictureAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Service provider", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue_setup_provider", sender: self)
}
actionSheetController.addAction(choosePictureAction)

// We need to provide a popover sourceView when using it on iPad
actionSheetController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender as UIView

// Present the AlertController
self.presentViewController(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 33):

**Updated for Swift 3.x, Swift 4.x, Swift 5.x**

```
// create an actionSheet
let actionSheetController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

// create an action
let firstAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "First Action", style: .default) { action -> Void in

    print("First Action pressed")
}

let secondAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Second Action", style: .default) { action -> Void in

    print("Second Action pressed")
}

let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { action -> Void in }

// add actions
actionSheetController.addAction(firstAction)
actionSheetController.addAction(secondAction)
actionSheetController.addAction(cancelAction)


// present an actionSheet...
// present(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)   // doesn't work for iPad

actionSheetController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = yourSourceViewName // works for both iPhone & iPad

present(actionSheetController, animated: true) {
    print("option menu presented")
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the screenshot as well. If you want RED text just change the style to .destructive

Answer (score 28):

Update for Swift 3:

```
// Create the AlertController and add its actions like button in ActionSheet
let actionSheetController = UIAlertController(title: "Please select", message: "Option to select", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

let cancelActionButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { action -> Void in
    print("Cancel")
}
actionSheetController.addAction(cancelActionButton)

let saveActionButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default) { action -> Void in
    print("Save")
}
actionSheetController.addAction(saveActionButton)

let deleteActionButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .default) { action -> Void in
    print("Delete")
}
actionSheetController.addAction(deleteActionButton)
self.present(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 27):

**Generetic Action Sheet working for Swift 4, 4.2, 5**

If you like a generic version that you can call from every `ViewController` and in every project try this one:

```
class Alerts {
 static func showActionsheet(viewController: UIViewController, title: String, message: String, actions: [(String, UIAlertActionStyle)], completion: @escaping (_ index: Int) -> Void) {
    let alertViewController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    for (index, (title, style)) in actions.enumerated() {
        let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: title, style: style) { (_) in
            completion(index)
        }
        alertViewController.addAction(alertAction)
     }
     // iPad Support
     alertViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = viewController.view
     
     viewController.present(alertViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Call like this in your ViewController.

```
    var actions: [(String, UIAlertActionStyle)] = []
    actions.append(("Action 1", UIAlertActionStyle.default))
    actions.append(("Action 2", UIAlertActionStyle.destructive))
    actions.append(("Action 3", UIAlertActionStyle.cancel))
    
    //self = ViewController
    Alerts.showActionsheet(viewController: self, title: "D_My ActionTitle", message: "General Message in Action Sheet", actions: actions) { (index) in
        print("call action \(index)")
        /*
         results
         call action 0
         call action 1
         call action 2
         */
    }
```

[image]

Attention: Maybe you're wondering why I add `Action 1/2/3` but got results like 0,1,2. In the line `for (index, (title, style)) in actions.enumerated()` I get the index of actions. Arrays always begin with the index 0. So the completion is 0,1,2.

If you like to set a enum, an id or another identifier I would recommend to hand over an object in parameter `actions`.

Comment: both  `title: String?` and        `message: String?` can be optional

Comment: @kuzdu - this works great, however crashes on ipad. can you update your answer for ipad ( setting sourceview and sourcerect) solves the problem

Comment: Could you please post the code which I should update? Or update my answer and I will accept

Answer (score 6):

**2022 Swift 5**

```swift
func yourActionSheet() -> UIAlertController {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Your title",
                                  message: nil,
                                  preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Your action 1",
                                  style: .default) { _ in
        // onAction1()
    })

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Your action 2",
                                  style: .default) { _ in
        // onAction2()
    })

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Your cancel action",
                                  style: .cancel) { _ in
        // onCancel
    })

    return alert
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Action Sheet in iOS10 with Swift3.0. Follow this link.

```
 @IBAction func ShowActionSheet(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // Create An UIAlertController with Action Sheet

    let optionMenuController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Choose Option from Action Sheet", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    // Create UIAlertAction for UIAlertController

    let addAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        print("File has been Add")
    })
    let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Edit", style: .default, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        print("File has been Edit")
    })

    let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .default, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        print("File has been Delete")
    })
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        print("Cancel")
    })

    // Add UIAlertAction in UIAlertController

    optionMenuController.addAction(addAction)
    optionMenuController.addAction(saveAction)
    optionMenuController.addAction(deleteAction)
    optionMenuController.addAction(cancelAction)

    // Present UIAlertController with Action Sheet

    self.present(optionMenuController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 3):

**SWIFT 4**

**WORKS ON IPHONE AND IPAD BOTH. ALSO ALLOWS ROTATION**

[image: LANDSCAPE] 
**LANDSCAPE**

[image: PORTRAIT]

**PORTRAIT**

***Code (tested)***

```
let alert = UIAlertController()

        let width: Int = Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 100)

        let viewAction    =     UIAlertAction(title: "View", style: .default , handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in
                                    let storyboard      =   UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                                    let orderDetailVC   =   storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "orderDetail") as! OrderDetailTableViewController

                                    orderDetailVC.orderId     =   self.myDraftOrders[indexPath.row]["id"].intValue

                                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(orderDetailVC, animated: true)
                                })

        viewAction.setValue(appGreenColor, forKey: "titleTextColor")

        alert.addAction(viewAction)

        let modifyAction    =   UIAlertAction(title: "Modify", style: .default, handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in
                                    showAlert("Coming soon...")
                                })

        modifyAction.setValue(appCyanColor, forKey: "titleTextColor")

        alert.addAction(modifyAction)

        let copyAction      =   UIAlertAction(title: "Copy", style: .default, handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in

                                    self.copyOrder(orderId: self.myDraftOrders[indexPath.row]["id"].intValue)

                                })

        copyAction.setValue(appBlueColor, forKey: "titleTextColor")

        alert.addAction(copyAction)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive , handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in

            self.deleteOrder(orderId: self.myDraftOrders[indexPath.row]["id"].intValue, indexPath: indexPath)

        }))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in
            print("User click Dismiss button")

        }))

        let popover = alert.popoverPresentationController

        popover?.delegate = self

        let cellT = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

        popover?.sourceView =   cellT
        popover?.sourceRect =   CGRect(x: width, y: 25, width: 100, height: 50)
        present(alert, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift :**

The sample code given below works both on iPhone and iPad.

```
 guard let viewRect = sender as? UIView else {
                return
            }

        let cameraSettingsAlert = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("Please choose a course", comment: ""), message: NSLocalizedString("", comment: ""), preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
        cameraSettingsAlert.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover

        let photoResolutionAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Photo Resolution", comment: ""), style: .Default) { action in

        }
        let cameraOrientationAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Camera Orientation", comment: ""), style: .Default) { action in

        }
        let flashModeAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Flash Mode", comment: ""), style: .Default) { action in

        }
        let timeStampOnPhotoAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Time Stamp on Photo", comment: ""), style: .Default) { action in

        }
        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Cancel", comment: ""), style: .Cancel) { action in

        }
        cameraSettingsAlert.addAction(cancel)
        cameraSettingsAlert.addAction(cameraOrientationAction)
        cameraSettingsAlert.addAction(flashModeAction)
        cameraSettingsAlert.addAction(timeStampOnPhotoAction)
        cameraSettingsAlert.addAction(photoResolutionAction)

        if let presenter = cameraSettingsAlert.popoverPresentationController {
            presenter.sourceView = viewRect;
            presenter.sourceRect = viewRect.bounds;
        }
        presentViewController(cameraSettingsAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

The Old Way: UIActionSheet

```
let actionSheet = UIActionSheet(title: "Takes the appearance of the bottom bar if specified; otherwise, same as UIActionSheetStyleDefault.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", destructiveButtonTitle: "Destroy", otherButtonTitles: "OK")
actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = .Default
actionSheet.showInView(self.view)

// MARK: UIActionSheetDelegate

func actionSheet(actionSheet: UIActionSheet, clickedButtonAtIndex  buttonIndex: Int) {
switch buttonIndex {
    ...
   }
}
```

The New Way: UIAlertController

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Takes the appearance of the bottom bar if specified; otherwise, same as UIActionSheetStyleDefault.", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { (action) in
  // ...
 }
 alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { (action) in
   // ...
}
alertController.addAction(OKAction)

let destroyAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Destroy", style: .Destructive) { (action) in
println(action)
}
alertController.addAction(destroyAction)

self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) {
// ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3**
For displaying UIAlertController from UIBarButtonItem on iPad

```
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Please Select an Option", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Approve", style: .default , handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in
        print("User click Approve button")
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Edit", style: .default , handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in
        print("User click Edit button")
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive , handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in
        print("User click Delete button")
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in
        print("User click Dismiss button")
    }))

    if let presenter = alert.popoverPresentationController {
        presenter.barButtonItem = sender
    }

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {
        print("completion block")
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

**swift4 (tested)**

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Select Photo", message: "Select atleast one photo", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "From Photo", style: .default) { (action) in
        print("Default is pressed.....")
    }
    let action2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action) in
        print("Cancel is pressed......")
    }
    let action3 = UIAlertAction(title: "Click new", style: .default) { (action) in
        print("Destructive is pressed....")

    }
    alertController.addAction(action1)
    alertController.addAction(action2)
    alertController.addAction(action3)
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Code for adding alerts to actionsheet in swift4**

```
   *That means when we click actionsheet values(like edit/ delete..so on) it shows 
   an alert option that is set with Yes or No option*


   class ViewController: UIViewController
   {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@IBAction func action_sheet1(_ sender: Any) {




    let action_sheet1 = UIAlertController(title: "Hi Bro", message: "Please Select an Option: ", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    action_sheet1.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Approve", style: .default , handler:{ (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        print("User click Approve button")



        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Approve", message: "Would you like to approve the file ", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))


        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }))




    action_sheet1.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Edit", style: .default , handler:{ (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        print("User click Edit button")

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Edit", message: "Would you like to edit the file ", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))


        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }))




    action_sheet1.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive , handler: { (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        print("User click Delete button")



        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Delete", message: "Would you like to delete the file permenently?", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))


        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }))





    action_sheet1.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "cancel", style: .cancel, handler:{ (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
         print("User click cancel button")


        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Cancel", message: "Would you like to cancel?", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))


        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }))



        self.present(action_sheet1, animated: true, completion: {
        print("completion block")
    })
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code for Alert and ActionSheet in Swift 4:

```
@IBAction func alert_act(_ sender: Any) {
    do {    
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Would you like to continue learning?", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
        
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
        
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

@IBAction func action_sheet1(_ sender: Any) {      
    let action_sheet1 = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Alert message.", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    
    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Default", style: .default, handler: nil)
    let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive, handler: nil)
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    
    action_sheet1.addAction(defaultAction)
    action_sheet1.addAction(deleteAction)
    action_sheet1.addAction(cancelAction)
    
    self.present(action_sheet1, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Useful to populate dynamic actions list, and listen to selected action:

```
var categories = ["Science", "History", "Industry", "Agriculture"]

var handlerSelectedCategory: ((Int) -> ())?

func prepareActions(for title: String, index: Int) -> UIAlertAction {

    let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: title, style: .default) { (action) in
        self.handlerSelectedCategory?(index)
    }

    return alertAction
}

@objc func presentActions() {

    let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    // add dymamic options
    for (index, element) in self.categories.enumerated() {
         optionMenu.addAction(prepareActions(for: element, index: index))
    }
    // cancel
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive)
    optionMenu.addAction(cancelAction)

    handlerSelectedCategory = { index in
        print(index, self.categories[index])
    }

    self.present(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5+
Very Simple and Smooth way just call this function and Boommmmmm!!!!!!!

```
let IPAD = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad


//Mark:- Choose Image Method
func funcMyActionSheet() {
    var myActionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.actionSheet)
    myActionSheet.view.tintColor = UIColor.black
    let galleryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery".localizableString(language: Defaults.selectedLanguageCode), style: .default, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        self.openGallary()
    })
    let cmaeraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera".localizableString(language: Defaults.selectedLanguageCode), style: .default, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        self.openCamera()
    })
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel".localizableString(language: Defaults.selectedLanguageCode), style: .cancel, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
    })
    

    if IPAD {
        //In iPad Change Rect to position Popover
        myActionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
    }
    myActionSheet.addAction(galleryAction)
    myActionSheet.addAction(cmaeraAction)
    myActionSheet.addAction(cancelAction)
    print("Action Sheet call")
    
    self.present(myActionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use following code for open actionSheet in Swift:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: enter your title, message: "Enter your messgage. ", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler(configurationTextField)

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in
    print("User click Cancel button")
}))

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in
    print("User click Ok button")
}))

self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: {
    print("completion block")
})
```

Comment: What should the configurationTextField be?

Comment: Here what you find :
 func configurationTextField(textField: UITextField!)
    {
        print("configurat hire the TextField")
        
        if textField != nil {
            
            self.textField = textField!
            self.textField.delegate = self
            //Save reference to the UITextField
            self.textField.text = ""
            self.textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad
            self.textField.placeholder = "Enter delay time in seconds"
        }
    }