# how to add my popup on viewcontroller programmatically in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to add popup programmatically to view controller.
i am trying this code but not working.

```
 [self.view addSubview:viewSelectZoneToAddVisit];
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SifBt.png)

Comment: Add full code . how you add popup.

Comment: Can you show some more code above this line and tell us how you load this view, from 1 line didn't get you, please explain more about your problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29887869/uiactionsheet-ios-swift/29888067#29888067 see this

Comment: i am create popup on xib and those popup connected to outlet and then i am add popup on viewcontroller so why is not add.

Comment: @mayankPalotra you need to shown the pop up to show line yes no on that popup with some massage

Comment: @MayankPalotra can you add the screen shot of your popup

Comment: @MayankPalotra Show us a line of code. How u are initialising the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    viewSelectZoneToAddVisit *viewSelectZoneToAddVisit = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"viewSelectZoneToAddVisit" owner:self options:nil][0]; // @"viewSelectZoneToAddVisit" is your XIB Name in Main Bundle
    [viewSelectZoneToAddVisit setFrame:(CGRect){0,0,300,400}]; // setting frame for your view
    [viewSelectZoneToAddVisit setCenter:self.view.center]; // set your view's center as self.view's center (Optional)
    [viewSelectZoneToAddVisit setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]]; // setting bg color
    // Design your sub views & Add them to viewSelectZoneToAddVisit


    // Finally add it as a subView of self.view
   [self.view addSubview:viewSelectZoneToAddVisit]; // adding it as a sub view for self.view
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For add child view controller

```
//add childview
    [self addChildViewController:yourViewControllerObject];
    [self.view addSubview:yourViewControllerObject.view];
    [yourViewControllerObject didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Remove from child view controller (add below code in your popup view for dismiss)

```
//remove from chiuld view controller
    [self removeFromParentViewController];
    [self didMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
```