# Ios collapsable and expandable bottom sheet

Tags: ios, bottom-sheet

I have used bottom sheet behavior in my android project.What is the alternative of bottom sheet behavior in ios? Can you help me about this?
is there any material component in ios like this?

Comment: checkout this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29887869/uiactionsheet-ios-swift)

Answer (score 1):

Hi there is so single component on `iOS` for the same.

Although, you can have two workarounds for the same

First you can make a `UIView` subclass call it `CollapseView` and design the view as you want your collapsed bottom view to look

Second you can make another `UIView` subclass call it `ExpandedView`

On tap of `CollapseView` hide it and show `ExpandedView` and vice versa
You can use animation methods for the hiding and showing
That will give the required collapsing and expanding effects.